# Dynamic cursor deleted record gets fetch again

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, cursor

I have #temp_fuel_que table has only three records with FUEL_NAME will be ('GCXFTSFUEL','GCXFTSLOSS','GCXFTSUAF'). and it gets deleted in as mention in following code. Since I created a dynamic cursor, my expectation is that, the while loop will not execute and it will come out of the loop after first time executing it. what's wrong in following code?

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TEST]
AS

   BEGIN

      /*  begin proc*/
      DECLARE  
        @que_id int,
        @que_fuel_name varchar(100)
            
         
         Create Table #temp_fuel_que
         (
            id int,
            fuel_name   varchar(100)
         )
        
    insert into #temp_fuel_que (id, fuel_name) values (1, 'GCXFTSFUEL')
    insert into #temp_fuel_que (id, fuel_name) values (2, 'GCXFTSLOSS')
    insert into #temp_fuel_que (id, fuel_name) values (3, 'GCXFTSUAF')

        
   SELECT * FROM #temp_fuel_que 
    
    DECLARE @que_cursor CURSOR
    SET @que_cursor = CURSOR DYNAMIC FOR --LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR 
            SELECT 
              #temp_fuel_que.id,
              #temp_fuel_que.fuel_name
            FROM #temp_fuel_que
            ORDER BY #temp_fuel_que.id
            

      OPEN @que_cursor

      FETCH next from @que_cursor
          INTO 
            @que_id, 
            @que_fuel_name

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0      
         BEGIN 

            print 'in while lool que_cursor @fuel_rate_cd : ' + cast(@que_fuel_name as varchar)
            
            
                IF (@que_fuel_name =  'GCXFTSFUEL')                             
                BEGIN
                    print 'in if - releated fuel'
                
                    delete #temp_fuel_que where #temp_fuel_que.fuel_name    in ('GCXFTSLOSS','GCXFTSUAF')
                
                    select * from #temp_fuel_que
                END             
                 
            
        
            FETCH next from @que_cursor
                INTO 
                  @que_id, 
                  @que_fuel_name

         END
         /*  que_cursor loop*/

      CLOSE @que_cursor

      DEALLOCATE @que_cursor

   END
```

when I execute this procedure I am getting following messages:

> (3 rows affected)

> (3 rows affected)
> in while lool que_cursor @fuel_rate_cd : GCXFTSFUEL
> @fuel_rate_cd: GCXFTSFUEL
> in if - releated fuel

> (2 rows affected)
> Msg 16929, Level 16, State 1, Procedure nvlp_fuel_recalc_que_KB3, Line 155 [Batch Start Line 1]
> The cursor is READ ONLY.
> The statement has been terminated.

> (1 row affected)
> in while lool que_cursor @fuel_rate_cd : GCXFTSLOSS
> @fuel_rate_cd: GCXFTSLOSS
> in while lool que_cursor @fuel_rate_cd : GCXFTSUAF
> @fuel_rate_cd: GCXFTSUAF

> Completion time: 2023-03-08T12:37:01.6425061-06:00

I google and tried all cursor dynamic examples but somehow my code is not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You have a very complex SP there, you surely don't expect anyone here to try and understand it do you? Provide a [mre] explaining what this SP does, provide sample data and desired results, and let us know at what point it goes wrong, and specifically how it goes wrong.

Comment: If i recall correctly, ORDER BY converts cursors to READ_ONLY unless you have some PK, or maybe always, the rules are kinda muddy. But whatever you're trying to do, dont' do it by using dynamic cursors

Comment: ok. how can I edit by previous ppost?

Comment: @siggemannen, thank you soooo very much. I have wasted so much time to figure out that was the issue, yes, after removing the "order by" it worked

Comment: Side note: You should not name your stored procedures with an "sp_" prefix. Microsoft reserves those names for its own use.